# CodeIgniter Form Validation greater_than_equal_to not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('MinimumSalary', 'Minimum Salary', 'trim|required|min_length[1]|max_length[20]|numeric|greater_than_equal_to[0]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('MaximumSalary', 'Maximum Salary', 'trim|required|min_length[1]|max_length[20]|numeric|greater_than_equal_to[MinimumSalary]');
```

and yet it always throws up an error when I enter MinimumSalary = 100 and MaximumSalary = 200, `The Maximum Salary field must contain a number greater than or equal to Minimum Salary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

```
'trim|required|min_length[1]|max_length[20]|numeric|greater_than_equal_to['.$this->input->post('MinimumSalary').']');
```

Comment: That works, except that the error message states the value of MinimumSalary instead of the field name. Not a big deal, but it's a nice to have